# Docker cannot remove network that already exists

Tags: docker

Kind of a strange situation - there's a network "omni_platform" and I cannot create it, however when I try to delete the network - Docker says it doesn't exist.

```
$ docker network create -d bridge omni_platform
Error response from daemon: network with name omni_platform already exists

$ docker network rm omni_platform
Error response from daemon: network s8gh5qljyaxyvjeespfsz86gn not found
```

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting  "network not found" in docker

1. Inspect the network which we are unable to delete

   ```
   docker network inspect [<id> or <name>]
   ```
2. Disconnect the network

   ```
   docker network disconnect -f [<networkID> or <networkName>] [<endpointName> or <endpointId>]
   ```
3. Delete unused networks

   ```
   docker network prune
   ```

Answer (score 8):

First, restart docker with this command:

```
 Service docker restart
```

Second,  list all networks which are already created. I guess the command is:

```
  docker network ls
```

Or

```
  docker network ps
```

Then you find ID of the network you want to delete and remove it with this:

```
   docker network rm ID
```

Hope it was helpful.